# How to grab array of string represented parameters in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function, parameters

I'm trying to grab an array of string represented parameters from a function and I'm unsure how to proceed. Basically given the function below

```
function MyFunc(param1, param2, param3){
  //do all the things
}
```

What would the function "getParams" look like to do the following

```
getParams(MyFunc) // ["param1","param2","param3"]
```

Comment: where do you want to use that `getParams`?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? The best you can do is convert the function to a string and then extract the parameters by some sort of simple parse.

Comment: I'm trying to achieve automated dependency injection in angular. So for example if I have a controller function MyCtrl($scope){} I can do

`MyCtrl.$inject = getParams(MyCtrl);`

Comment: @FrostwareCEO don't build matchbox house

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit messy, but you can do this by converting your function to a string and then splitting it until you get just the parameters:

```
var getFuncParams = function(MyFunc) {
    var str = MyFunc.toString()
    var strParams = str.substr((str.indexOf('(')+1), (str.indexOf(')') - str.indexOf('(')) - 1)
    var params = strParams.split(",")
    return params;
}
```

Comment: this seems to accomplish exactly what I was trying to do thanks!

Comment: No problem - I've edited it slightly to be inside it's own function. Hope it helps!